# Angular CLI: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery__(...).collapse is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have an Angular App Component generated via the CLI (Angular 4).

I've brought in jQuery + Bootstrap like so:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

My App Component looks like so:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [

    './app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    $('.nav a').click(function () {
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
  }
}
```

Receiving the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery__(...).collapse is not a function
```

Is Bootstrap not being imported properly? I've tried adding the following to the top of my component:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
```

**EDIT:**

One thing I've noticed. When running in the browser if I execute the following line through the Chrome Console it works without issue:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
```

What would be the difference here? I must be missing something.

Comment: Have you tried declaring jquery globally , you will miss the typings though. Instead of:
import * as $ from 'jquery';
use
declare var $:any;

Comment: not understanding what the difference would be here?

Comment: Do you have any minimal example to reproduce it?

Comment: @aherrick. Because Bootstrap requires jquery as global, The following link might help https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/12/External-JavaScript-dependencies-in-Typescript-and-Angular-2#jQueryandPlugins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment , it seems to be an issue of Bootstrap requiring jquery to be global. A very similar question is answered in the following link :-

[2 fullcalender instances in Angular component causes jquery not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990890/2-fullcalender-instances-in-angular-component-causes-jquery-not-found-error)

The other option is define types for collapse as mentioned in -cloud's answer

Answer (score 27):

The below step resolved this issue for me..

I replaced the jquery import command in the component from

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

to

```
declare var $ : any;
```

Comment: what is this change does actually? it worked for me. Just curious

Comment: Hero of the day!

Comment: YOU ARE THE GENIUS!

Answer (score 4):

You should not specify your dependencies like that.

Since you've installed bootstrap and jQuery via npm/yarn, you ought to import them directly like `import * as $ from 'jquery';` without configure something else. No `scripts` is needed.

`scripts` config is supposed to be treated as global script as script tag inside `index.html`, see [the scripts story here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts).

Since `collapse` is a jquery plugin from `bootstrap`, you should do something like

```
interface JQuery {
  collapse(options?: any): any;
}
```

to let typescript know its types.

#### update #1

you can install `@types/bootstrap` to skip defining the interfaces.

Comment: not sure I follow. Where does the interface collapse code go and why is it required? shouldn't it work regardless of types?

Comment: **type**script, type is the most important feature. If typescript doesn't know what `collapse` method is, it just complains about it like you have.

Answer (score 3):

Follow my steps

1) Install jQuery. (skip if already installed)

```
npm install jquery --save
```

2) Install types for jQuery.

```
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

3) Import jQuery in **app.module.ts.**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

4) Install bootstrap 3 not 4, so remove any bootstrap.bundle.min.js in **angular.json**

```
npm install bootstrap@3 --save
```

5) Add correct injection in **angular.json**, the order is important

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

6) in the file where you use $(element).collapse add this after the imports

```
    declare var $: any;
```

7) now you can use

```
    $(element).collapse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try calling jquery like :

```
    import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';
```

Comment: it does not matter